# Why is git2r failing to install?

Tags: r, devtools, libssh2, libssl

When I try to install `devtools` in R via RStudio Server on my Red Hat Linux machine it fails because it cannot install `git2r`. When I then try to install `git2r`, it fails to install.

I think it might be because I need to install `libssh2` on my Linux machine based on the following warning. Is that correct? If so, that could be corrected with a `yum install libssh2-devel` from the Linux command line, correct? Unfortunately, I'm waiting on my admin to give me `sudo` privileges, so I can't test that hypothesis yet.

```
configure: WARNING:
  ---------------------------------------------
   Unable to find the LibSSH2 library on this
   system. Building a version without support
   for SSH transport.

   To build with SSH support, please install:
     libssh2-1-dev (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
     libssh2-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
     libssh2 (Homebrew package on OS X)
   and try again.

   If the LibSSH2 library is installed on
   your system but the git2r configuration
   is unable to find it, you can specify
   the include and lib path to LibSSH2 with:
   R CMD INSTALL git2r --configure-vars='LIBS=-L/path/to/libs CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/headers'
  ---------------------------------------------
```

There is also a warning at the end of the failed install output that mentions `libssl`. Is that related to `libssh2` or a separate issue? If separate, how would I fix it? Is there a `libssl` library I should install or something?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘git2r’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/jp7663/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r/libs/git2r.so':
  libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/jp7663/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You do need libssl; whether you need libssh2 depends on how you plan to use it. As the warning says, "To build **with SSH support**, please install:" (emphasis added). If you don't care about that, you don't need libssh2, but libssl is an actual system dependency.

Comment: @duckmayr That makes sense, so I tried to install `openssl-devel` (I now have `sudo` privileges) but I got a message that it was already installed `[root@prdawspackrsh01 ~]# yum install openssl-devel
Loaded plugins: depsonly, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` Is there another library for `libssl` other than `openssl` that I should be installing?

Comment: What does `which openssl` output?